# How to get a martingale?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Given is $(X_{t})_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of bounded independent random variables which are not $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. constant. Let $S_{t}=\sum^{t}_{i=1}X_{i}X_{i+1}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{X}_{t}= \sigma(X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots, X_{t})$.

I am trying to figure out when is $S_{t}$ an $\mathcal{(F}^{X}_{t})$-martingale.

According to the definition of a martingale, we need 3 conditions to be satisfied:

1)Every $X_{t}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t}$-measurable for each $t \in \mathbb{N_{0}}$.

2)$\mathbb{E}[X_{t}]< \infty$ for each $t \in \mathbb{N_{0}}$.

3)$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[X_{t+1} \rvert \mathcal{F}^{X}]=X_{t}$ for every $t \in \mathbb{N_{0}}$.

Can anybody help me with this question, please? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should have written $S_{t}= \sum_{i=1}^{t-1}X_{i}X_{i+1}$. In that case one possible situation is when $E(X_{n})= 0$ for all $n$, and is adapted process (that is X_{n} is $n$-measurable). 
You can see this $E(S_{n+1}|F_{n}) = S_{n}+ E(X_{n}X_{n+1}|F_{n}) =S_{n}+X_{n}E(X_{n+1}|F_{n})= S_{n}$.

Comment: And if the $X_n$ are non-degenerate, the condition $E(X_n)=0$ for all $n\ge 1$ is necessary.